# React Navigation v4 lifecycle events do not fire when navigating to the same screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Let's say I have a `ProductScreen` component that renders info about a product as well as a list of other similar products. When clicking on a similar product, a navigation is done from `ProductScreen` ==> `ProductScreen` with different params/key.

The problem I'm facing is that I want to do something on the React Navigation focus event (for example, scroll to top)

```
navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
  console.log('didFocus')
  scrollToTop()
})
```

I see the log the first time the component renders, but when doing a navigation from `ProductScreen` ==> `ProductScreen`, the `didFocus` event doesn't seem to be firing again so the component isn't scrolled to the top. In fact, none of the lifecycle events (`willFocus`, `didFocus`, `willBlur`, `didBlur`) seem to be firing.

Is there any way to be able to use react navigation lifecycle events when navigating from component X to component X with different params? Thanks!

Comment: did you provide a different `id` in the navigation action? This way you are generating a new instance of the Component instead of reusing it.

Comment: it would be something like `navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'Product', params: { product: product }, key: product.id })` and the `product.id` would be different. The navigation itself is working, but the lifecycle events aren't firing.

Comment: I am not sure how RN navigation manages the re-use or create-new, but what worked for me was to add an `id: new Date().getTime()` to the `params`-Object

Answer (score 0):

You're navigating to the same screen so it's normal that `didFocus` doesn't fire, since the screen was already focused.

If you want to react to params change, you can use `componentDidUpdate`/`useEffect` to compare previous params with the new params and do what you need to do.

If you want to navigate to a new screen, you can use `push` instead of `navigate`